# Reflexive Sheaf and Blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a blowup along of a subvariety $V \subset Y$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a reflexive coherent sheaf on $Y$. Is $f^{*}\mathcal{F}$ reflexive on $X$? Thank you.

Comment: In general it is not reflexive. Your title suggests (not mentioned in the body of the question) that you are interested in the case when $f$ is a blowing up and then in general it may not be.

Comment: Ok. It's true. I apologize. I edited the question. Thanks for the  reply, Mohan.

Comment: @AllanRamos https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127648/reflexive-sheaf

Comment: @Qixiao. Thank you very much.